# iPhone UITableView cells stay selected

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

in my UITableView sometimes cells stay selected after touching.
Because it happens only occasionally, I'm not able to reproduce the
problem.

Any hints? Maybe it has something to do with unproper releasing of tableView?

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{   
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

switch (row) {
    case 0:
        FruitViewController *fruitController = [FruitViewController alloc];
        [fruitController retain];
        [fruitController initWithNibName:@"FruitView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fruitController animated:YES];
        [fruitController release];
        break;
    case 1: 
        CerealsViewController *cerealsController = [CerealsViewController alloc];
        [cerealsController retain];
        [cerealsController initWithNibName:@"CerealsView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:cerealsController animated:YES];
        [cerealsController release];
        break;
    default:
        break;   
}
   }
```

Comment: Maybe you override viewWillAppear:animated without calling [super viewWillAppear:animated] ?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I can't tell you why you're seeing the issue, but here are some suggestions for fixing it:

According to the Apple HIG, the selection should not disappear until returning from the view controller just pushed onto the stack.  If your controller is just a UITableViewController, it should deselect automatically upon returning to the view.  If not, add

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

somewhere in the view controller.

If there are any rows that, when clicked, do not go to another view, and don't in fact do anything when selected, they shouldn't be selectable, so you can override that in

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and return `nil` in the cases that the row should not be selected.

Answer (score 21):

One possible cause is overriding `-viewWillAppear:animated:` without calling `[super viewWillAppear]` in a controller that extends `UITableViewController`.  Adding `[super viewWillAppear:animated]` at the beginning of your `-viewWillAppear` method may rectify the problem.

Answer (score 10):

Just to expand on "Ed Marty"s answer, I chose to add the deselect in the "viewWillDisappear" method instead because I thought that it looked nicer.

In addition to this I was using a UITableView with a regular UIViewController (rather than a UITableViewController) so the tableView variable wasn't available to me.  To overcome this I added a tableView property in my view controllers header file (and in my XIB file I connected the actual table view to the property)...

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView
```

...and in the view controllers implementation wired up the property and performed the deselect as follows..

```
@synthesize tableView

- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:animated];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

Comment: This solution is the best as the selected answer does not work in navigation controller

Answer (score 8):

If you are using a UITableViewController you can use:

```
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;
```

Comment: Where can I put this?

Comment: try it on your viewDidLoad or ViewWillAppear @GajendraKChauhan

Comment: @VanDuTran, how did you implement your viewcontroller? by nib, or storyboard? can you also try it from -(void)awakeFromNib? because when you create a master-detail sample project from xcode, you will see some codes generated by Apple in awakeFromNib, 'self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO' so it should work.

Comment: I use storyboard and the Table View Controller object. It generates the code self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear, I changed to YES. It works when you present/dismiss view controllers.. but not when you tap on a cell that brings you to another app (ex: safari), then come back.

Comment: @VanDuTran then check the answer from above, try Deselecting the row in didSelectRowatIndexPath                                                 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Go to Safari or other app

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
}

Answer (score 4):

In my case , i deselect the cell right at the end of didSelectRowAtIndexPath :

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Do smth here. segue ..etc

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in your `UITableViewCell` class

```
(void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

// Just comment This line of code

// [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}
```

or even you can try this code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 
     // Do some stuff when the row is selected

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Solving this takes about two seconds once you learn how tables are managed.

**As soon as cells are scrolled off screen, they lose their formatting.** The table minimizes its memory usage by dismissing the other cells and recreating them if/when the user scroll back.

Even things like reloading table data, that really only applies to the cells on screen at that moment. Point being, the cellForRowAtIndexPath might create the same cell five times without the user ever hitting a button or leaving the view controller! So set it up to reload any formatting. Add something like this to cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
    if arrayOf_SelectedCells.contains(indexPath) {
        setup_Selected(cell)
        //Where setup_Selected is a custom function to apply formatt
    } else {
        setup_Unselected(cell)
    }
```