# When select cell, UITableView changing appearance when scroll?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have the strangest glitch after I select a UITableView cell and scroll away([You can see it here](https://vid.me/RtL6)):

When I select a cell, it's programmed to change its text and change the font color from brown to red. However, when I scroll, other cells that I have not selected change their font color to red. And when I scroll back to the selected cell it reverts to its original text and *sometimes*, its font color too (from red to brown).

I've used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275405/uitableview-selected-cell-doesnt-stay-selected-when-scrolled) in attempt to fix it. But still the glitch remains.

I am completely baffled as to why this is happening and would love love *love* if anyone could tell me why.

In my code I made my `ViewController CategoryViewController` the `UITableView`'s `Datasource` & `Delegate` instead of a `UITableViewController` b/c I have other views in my `CategoryViewController`, not just a `UITableView`

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    private let themeColors = ThemeColors()
    private let expensesOrganizer = ExpensesOrganizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Set up subCategory table view
        subCategoryTableView.dataSource = self
        subCategoryTableView.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDataSource

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return expensesOrganizer.getNumOfSubcategoriesFor(category!)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let subcategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subCategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubcategoryTableViewCell
        let subcategory = expensesOrganizer.getSubcategoryFor(category!, index: indexPath.row)
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row) \(expensesOrganizer.getText(subcategory.rawValue))"
        subcategoryCell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        subcategoryCell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = themeColors.getColorOfCategory(category!)

        return subcategoryCell
    }

    // MARK: UITableViewDelegate

    var indexPathSelectedCell: NSIndexPath?

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let subcategoryCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubcategoryTableViewCell
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row) didSELECTRowAtIndexPath called"
        indexPathSelectedCell = indexPath

       //What the post said to add:
        let selectedRows = subCategoryTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
        for i in selectedRows! {
            if !i.isEqual(indexPath){
                subCategoryTableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(i, animated: false)
            }
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let subcategoryCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! SubcategoryTableViewCell
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.textColor = themeColors.getFontColor(Shade.Light)
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row) didDESELECTRowAtIndexPath called"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The approach that you take is incorrect, because you are *not* setting the color when you reuse a cell. Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` needs to set color back to brown if the cell is not selected. It should be set to red if the cell is selected:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let subcategoryCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("subCategoryCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SubcategoryTableViewCell
    let subcategory = expensesOrganizer.getSubcategoryFor(category!, index: indexPath.row)
    subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row) \(expensesOrganizer.getText(subcategory.rawValue))"
    subcategoryCell.selectedBackgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    subcategoryCell.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = themeColors.getColorOfCategory(category!)
    if let selected = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as? [NSIndexPath] && selected! == indexPath {
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.textColor = UIColor.brownColor()            
    } else {
        subcategoryCell.subCategoryLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    return subcategoryCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with cell reuse.

When you change the color of the label in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, then scroll that cell off-screen, it gets reused for a different cell that will appear on-screen.

However, since you don't prepare the cell for reuse, it is still using the selected font color for your label.

Assigning the label's default text color in `prepareForReuse` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will fix this issue.