# Scrolling between sections in UITableView with selected cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, selection, sections

I have a UITableView with two sections and I have a button which changes the tableview to edit mode but only the bottom section is editable.

When I select rows and scroll only in the bottom section (which is in edit mode) the rows keep there selection. But if I scroll up until the bottom section is hidden and return back the bottom section the selection has been cleared.

The scrolling between the sections clears the selection.

Why is this happening? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITableView selected cell doesn't stay selected when scrolled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275405/uitableview-selected-cell-doesnt-stay-selected-when-scrolled)

Comment: Do you have two different cell identifiers for the two sections?

Comment: No, they are the same because they are the same cell from the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @Magoo, you put me in the right direction to fix my bug. I needed 2 different identifiers for the 2 sections.

Comment: Cool... and you're welcome:) I'll post it up whynot

Answer (score 0):

So just for posterity. In general even if tableview cells are the same class if they have different behaviour when it comes to things like editabilty it's often better to have two separate CellIdentifier strings to avoid a lot of switching between states.

Can be as simple as

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";


NSString *identifierString = indexPath.section == 0 ? CellIdentifier:CellIdentifier2;

MYTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifierString];

if (!cell)
    cell = [[MYTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifierString];
```